# Парсинг массива и обработка данных в JS коде. Как пройти ошибку?

Tags: javascript

Как пройти ошибку?

Есть задача: удаление из массива всех строк ***что идут выше трёх подряд идущих строк в конце которых есть знаки препинания*** (знаки препинания определены в массиве  [[SYMBOLS]] )

Есть JS код для этого (его я привёл в конце этой темы). Кодом обрабатываю этот массив текста но получаю ошибку:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token Я in JSON at position 1`

Сразу поясню 3 нюанса:

***1)*** Многострочный список строк (массив) в моём интерпретаторе JS задаётся в виде оборачивания в ***[[]]***.
Для языка JS он является ***массивом*** (Массив - он же объект).

Например, вот так выглядит массив ***[[1AA]]*** (см. скрин ниже) текст тут дан как пример, поэтому текст может быть любым:

[image: 1AA]

***2)*** Вставить многострочный массив в JS код в таком виде (в виде строки) нельзя, так как тексты внутри ***[[1AA]]*** могут быть любые:

```
let text = `Я видел огненные знаки
Чудес, рожденных на заре
Я вышел — пламенные маки,
Сложить на горном алтаре.
Со мною утро в дымных ризах,
Кадило в голубую твердь,
И на уступах, на карнизах`;
```

***3)*** Нужно определять только так:
Присваиваем переменной ***text*** массив [[1AA]]

`let text = [[1AA]];`

**Как я пытаюсь решить эту задачу:**
В коде Яваскрипта сначала делаю распарс с помощью ***JSON.parse*** преобразуя массив ***[[1AA]]*** в строку вот так:

```
let text = [[1AA]];
var qqq = JSON.parse("[" + text + "]");
let str = qqq.split(',');
```

***А тут собственно весь JS код  :***

```js
let text = [[1AA]];
var qqq = JSON.parse("[" + text + "]");
let str = qqq.split(',');
const punct = [[SYMBOLS]];
const numStrWithPunctEnd = 3;
const arr = str.split('\n');
const index = arr.findIndex(function(n, i, a) {
  return this.every(m => punct.includes(a[i + m].slice(-1)));
}, [...Array(numStrWithPunctEnd).keys()]);
const result = index !== -1 ? arr.slice(index).join('\n') : str;
[[1AA]]=result;
```

При обработке всего приведённого выше JSкода я получаю ошибку, как её пройти?

Comment: Вообще Вы делаете какую-то дичь, ну для начала.  "распарс с помощью JSON.parse преобразуя массив [[1AA]] в строку" - JSON.parse, как видно из его названия, парсит строку в JS-сущность, а не наоборот.

Comment: Ок, предположим у нас в переменой text многострочный массив, как его обработать по условию: удаление из массива всех строк что идут выше трёх подряд идущих строк в конце которых есть знаки препинания (знаки препинания определены в массиве [[SYMBOLS]] )

Вот чтоб вот по такой схеме осталось:
https://habrastorage.org/webt/62/5c/86/625c867b52917556240096.jpeg

Comment: Вот код, но не пойму почему не работает:
`let str = ["двенадцать яблок", "Апельсин.", "Слива.", "два ананаса.", "семь киви."];
const punct = [[SYMBOLS]];
const numStrWithPunctEnd = 3;
const arr = str.split('\n');
const index = arr.findIndex(function(n, i, a) {
  return this.every(m => punct.includes(a[i + m].slice(-1)));
}, [...Array(numStrWithPunctEnd).keys()]);
const result = index !== -1 ? arr.slice(index).join('\n') : str;
console.log(result);`

Comment: А можете закрепить в вопросе: 1. Данные до обработки. 2. Что должно получится. А то по сути вы показали промежуточную обработку и "что нужно сделать". Примеров я не увидел.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас каша где массив, где строка:

```
const SYMBOLS = [',','.','?','!',':',';'];
const str =   `двенадцать яблок
двенадцать яблок
двенадцать яблок
двенадцать яблок
двенадцать яблок
двенадцать яблок
двенадцать яблок
Апельсин.
Слива.
два ананаса.
семь киви.`

let arr = str.split("\n");
const numStrWithPunctEnd = 3;

const index = arr.findIndex(
  function (n, i, a) {
    return this.every((m) => SYMBOLS.includes(a[i + m].slice(-1)));
  },
  [...Array(numStrWithPunctEnd).keys()]
);
const result = index !== -1 ? arr.slice(index).join('\n') : str;
console.log(result);
```